# Sending object(json) using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

Im trying to send json object in Outlook using vba. Here is my code:

```
Dim Msg As Outlook.MeetingItem
Set Msg = Item
Set recips = Msg.Recipients
Dim regEx As New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "^\w+\s\w+,\sI351$"
Dim URL As String
URL = "https://webhook.site/55759d1a-7892-4c20-8d15-3b8b7f1bf3b3"

For Each recip In recips
    If regEx.Test(recip.AddressEntry) And recip.AddressEntry <> "Application Management Linux1, I351" Then
        Dim convertedJson As Object
        Set convertedJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""fields"": 123}")
        Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        xhr.Open "POST", URL, False
        xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        xhr.Send (convertedJson)
    End If
Next
```

If I send just plane text it works well but i can't send `convertedJson`. Is it possible to send an object?

**UPDATE**

I can't even do `Debug.Print convertedJson`

[image]

Comment: what do you mean converted?  JSON **is** plain text.  What do you mean "email an object"?  It seems to me, that's kind of like wrapping up a digital photo in paper.  [Are you referring to **PrettyPrint**](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+prettyprint) or something like that?  What should this email look like?

Comment: @ashleedawg I explaned it here but still no one didn't answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247251/how-to-parse-json-from-email-in-outlook

Comment: many examples of JSON parsing on this blog http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-bang-syntax-part2-json-parsing.html of note there is the calling on the javascript function JSON.stringify which comes form Douglas Crockford who popularised JSON.  The function is loaded into a script control.  Other options are to wrap a COM DLL around the C# llbrary Newtosoft.Json , http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-c-bang-syntax-part-3-c-interop-json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tormented by these libraries in the end I did a very terrible thing

```
Dim flds, prt, id, smry, descrp, issu, name, lfbrkt, rtbrkt, cma, dbdots, jsTest, issuName As String
flds = "'fields'"
prt = "'project'"
id = "'id'"
smry = "'summary'"
descrp = "'description'"
issu = "'issuetype'"
issuName = "'Improvement'"
name = "'name'"
lfbrkt = "{"
rtbrkt = "}"
cma = ","
dbdots = ":"
jsTest = lfbrkt + flds + dbdots + " " + lfbrkt + vbCrLf + vbTab + prt + dbdots + " " + lfbrkt + vbCrLf + vbTab + vbTab + id + dbdots + " " + "30611" + vbCrLf + vbTab + rtbrkt + cma + vbCrLf + vbTab + smry + dbdots + " " + "'" + CStr(Msg.Subject) + "'" + cma + vbCrLf + vbTab + descrp + dbdots + " " + "'" + CStr(Msg.Body) + "'" + cma + vbCrLf + vbTab + issu + dbdots + " " + lfbrkt + vbCrLf + vbTab + vbTab + name + dbdots + " " + issuName + vbCrLf + vbTab + rtbrkt + vbCrLf + rtbrkt + rtbrkt
```

And I got this

[image]